# Flutter: DateTime error "The method '~/' was called on null."

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetimepicker

I am currently coding an app and I get this weird error "The method '~/' was called on null.".
I have a main page where I add a ListView entry. When I click on it pass me to another page where I can add a date and time to a ListView. It works fine. But when I go back with the arrow in the top left corner and open the same page again I get this error. And it shows me that the error occurs on the DateTime. Have someone a solution?

```
return ListTile(
     title: Text( "${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].zeitVon).hour}:
                   ${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].zeitVon).minute} - 
                   ${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].zeitBis).hour}:
                   ${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].zeitBis).minute}"),

    subtitle: Text( "${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].datum).day}.
                     ${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].datum).month}.
                     ${DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(zeiten[index].datum).year}"),
    trailing: Text("${zeiten[index].gesamtBetrag} €"),
    );
```

Comment: What is the stack trace?  Look at where the exception occurred and work backward to trace where the null value came from.

Comment: Almost always, "called on null" means you didn't wait properly for a Future.  Possible here?

Comment: Nevermind I had a little twist in my "zeiten" class. It tries to call "zeiten.zeitVon" but I wrote, "zeiten.zeitBis". But thanks for your ideas.